# SharePoint for education

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to figure out if it’s possible to create learning material for a course that I am teaching something equivalent to in the format of book and chapters like https://demo.bookstackapp.com/books/dummy-content-book.

I was wondering what are the equipment of Books, Chapters, and pages in SharePoint would be.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Sharepoint document library name as the Books name, divide the books into multiple folders by Chapters and store them in the document library, and create subfolders in the folders to store smaller chapters or store content directly.

You can set individual permissions for each subfolders, folders, document libraries. For example, those that have been taught to students can be opened to all students to see, and those that have not been taught cannot be seen, etc.

Comment: I know Library is great option but I would like to use sites/pages for books/chapters more like an interactive content.

Comment: That might require you to do custom development.